# Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method

Tags: json, flutter, class, dart

I have some code to get files from a json file, only I get a message and not know how to solve that, any ideas?:

```
List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

@override
  void initState() {
    polylineCoordinates = readJson().map((e)=> LatLng(e['lat'], e['long'])).tolist();
    super.initState();
  }
```

The error is:

```
Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method 'map'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => LatLng)
```

Comment: what package do you use for readJson?

Comment: can you show the LatLng class code?

Comment: Your readJson method should return a List or Iterable. Here it returns a Future, which has no map method.